# postgresql option for developer - wal_debug

Tags: postgresql

I want to set `wal_debug` on to my `postgresql.conf` so that I can see what's happening with the write-ahead log (WAL).

I compiled PostgreSQL with `--enable-debug`:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pgsql --enable-nls --with-perl --with-libxml --with-pam --enable-debug
```

and added this to the buttom of `postgresql.conf`

```
wal_debug = on
```

When I tried to start postgres the server complains:

```
$ pg_ctl start
server starting
FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "wal_debug"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-developer.html says: 'This parameter is only available if the WAL_DEBUG macro was defined when PostgreSQL was compiled.'

Comment: `--enable-debug` has nothing to do with this.  See also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/install-procedure.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When configuring, pass `-DWAL_DEBUG` in the `CPPFLAGS` to `./configure`, eg:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS='-DWAL_DEBUG'
```

All `--enable-debug` does (in Pg) is tell the compiler to emit an additional section in each compilation unit that contains debug info - function parameters, local variable info, etc. This info allows useful backtraces to be produced when debugging with `gdb`, makes it easier to step through the program, etc.

Other debug and test options are controlled by pre-processor definitions like `WAL_DEBUG`, which are tested for with conditional compilation directives like `#ifdef WAL_DEBUG` within the source code. A few of these have configure flags, like `--enable-cassert`, but for most you're just expected to pass the preprocessor flag yourself.

As pointed out by dezso, see:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-procedure.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-developer.html